# Filtering data by two table using Linq to Entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

I have a two table.First is Post table, second is Userlike table where i save users like for current post. And need to filtering posts by userlikes in Userlike table.

```
var posts = from p in db.Posts 
orderby 
   (from pc in db.UserLikes 
    where pc.PostID == p.PostID 
    select pc.user_like == true)
   .Count() 
descending select p;
```

[image: This is my tables]

Comment: Please show what have you tried

Comment: ###this is my code ###var posts = from p in db.Posts
                        orderby (from pc in db.UserLikes where pc.PostID==p.PostID
                                 select pc.user_like==true
                                 ).Count() descending
                        select p;

Comment: And what you're trying to achive?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }


    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }

        public User User { get; set; }

        public string Tilte { get; set; }

        //.....
    }

    public class UserLike
    {
        public int LikeId { get; set; }

        public int PostId { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        User user = Repository.GetCurrentUser();
        List<UserLike> userLikes = Repository.GetUserLikes();

        userLikes.Where(x => x.UserId == user.UserId).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  IQueryable<User> users = (new[]
  {
    new User {Id = 1, Likes = new HashSet<UserLike>(new[] {new UserLike(), new UserLike(), })},
    new User {Id = 2, Likes = new HashSet<UserLike>(new[] {new UserLike(), })},
    new User {Id = 1, Likes = new HashSet<UserLike>(new[] {new UserLike(), new UserLike(),new UserLike() })}
  }).AsQueryable();

  var query = from u in users
    orderby u.Likes.Count(x => x.Liked)
    select u;
```